# bash can a sourced script tell if a getops has been passed to parent

Tags: bash, getopts

I am wondering if & how a sourced bash script can tell if a getops variable was passed to a parent, such as,

```
.parent.sh -a MyVarForChild_a
```

in the `parent.sh` I call `. child.sh` and I would like to check if the -a MyVar was passed. I would prefer NOT to use the getops var in the parent and set the var if possible, rather use something similar to getops in the child to test if that var was passed, then set it.

**parent.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x

#confirm bash or dash (ec2)
echo $SHELL

child_a="/home/userX/child_a.sh"
. ${child_a} "$@" -b TestVar
```

**child_a.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x

while getopts "a:b:" OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
        a)
            MyPassedVar=$OPTARG 
            ;;
        b)
            MyTestVar=$OPTARG 
            ;;     
       esac
done

echo $MyPassedVar
echo $MyTestVar
```

thx, Art

**UPDATED for feedback as below answers....**

The below answer from @Robin Hsu works for the above code and is a valid answer for the question asked and outputs

```
$ /home/userX/parent.sh -a ThisIsPassed
+ echo /bin/bash
/bin/bash
+ child_a=/home/userX/child_a.sh
+ . /home/userX/child_a.sh -a ThisIsPassed -b TestVar
++ set -x
++ getopts a:b: OPTION
++ case $OPTION in
++ MyPassedVar=ThisIsPassed
++ getopts a:b: OPTION
++ case $OPTION in
++ MyTestVar=TestVar
++ getopts a:b: OPTION
++ echo ThisIsPassed
ThisIsPassed
++ echo TestVar
TestVar
```

However it seems getops will only be executed once per parent & child, so adding getops in the parent will stop it working in the child, such as

**parent.sh (ver2)**

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x
#confirm bash or dash (ec2)
echo $SHELL

while getopts "x:" OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
        x)
            MyXvar_notPassed=$OPTARG 
            ;;
       esac
done

child_a="/home/userX/child_a.sh"
. ${child_a} "$@" -b TestVar
```

outputs

```
$ /home/userX/parent.sh -a ThisIsPassed
+ echo /bin/bash
/bin/bash
+ getopts x: OPTION
/home/userX/parent.sh: illegal option -- a
+ case $OPTION in
+ getopts x: OPTION
+ child_A=/home/userX/child_a.sh
+ . /home/userX/child_a.sh -a ThisIsPassed -b TestVar
++ set -x
++ getopts a:b: OPTION
++ echo

++ echo
```

additionally if I add a 2nd child script, the 2nd child (child_b) fails the getops,

**parent.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x

#confirm bash or dash (ec2)
echo $SHELL

child_a="/home/userX/child_a.sh"
. ${child_a} "$@" -b TestVar

child_b="/home/userX/child_b.sh"
. ${child_a} "$@" -z OtherVar
```

**child_a.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x

while getopts "a:b:" OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
        a)
            MyPassedVar=$OPTARG 
            ;;
        b)
            MyTestVar=$OPTARG 
            ;;     
       esac
done

echo $MyPassedVar
echo $MyTestVar
```

**child_b.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x

while getopts "a:z:" OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
        a)
            MyPassedVarA=$OPTARG 
            ;;
        z)
            MyOtherVar=$OPTARG 
            ;;     
       esac
done

echo $MyPassedVarA
echo $MyOtherVar
```

outputting

```
$ /home/userX/parent.sh -a ThisIsPassed
+ echo /bin/bash
/bin/bash
+ child_a=/home/userX/child_a.sh
+ . /home/userX/child_a.sh -a ThisIsPassed -b TestVar
++ set -x
++ getopts a:b: OPTION
++ case $OPTION in
++ MyPassedVar=ThisIsPassed
++ getopts a:b: OPTION
++ case $OPTION in
++ MyTestVar=TestVar
++ getopts a:b: OPTION
++ echo ThisIsPassed
ThisIsPassed
++ echo TestVar
TestVar
+ child_b=/home/userX/child_b.sh
+ . /home/userX/child_b.sh -a ThisIsPassed -z OtherVar
++ set -x
++ getopts a:z: OPTION
++ echo

++ echo
```

**Supplemental question**

How can I have a parent + children with each child having a getops?

thx
Art

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`. child.sh` has its own argument list.  This means it is legal for child.sh to receive arguments in command line like this:

```
. child.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

So, I think if you want to pass the vars, you need to do this:

```
. child.sh "$@"
```

**--Update--**
To your further question, you should write your script mimic to the one you wrote, for the getopts part, like this:

```
while getopts "a:b:" OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
       a)
            MyPassedVar=$OPTARG 
            ;;
       b)
            MyOptionB=$OPTARG
            ;;
       esac
done

echo $MyPassedVar
echo $MyOptionB
```

--update--
try

```
.  ./child.sh "$@"
```

It seems that bash can accept `child.sh` (if your parent script starts with #!/bin/bash), but sh can only accept `./child.sh`

Comment: meaning that your getopts loop is processing an empty argument list, since you script sources child.sh without arguments.

Comment: thx @Robin, it looks like the var is now being passed. If I set -x I see '. child.sh -a MyVAr', however the child.sh still does not pick up that -a is set.

Comment: thx @Robin, still no luck after adding quotes to the call "$@" the script still only reports the -b TestVar in getops

Comment: It's running fine in my machine.  Could you post a more complete version? Apparently your updated question does not contains -b part for the child.sh